# Join the HashCode magic

Tags: c#, .net

am started testing hash function on the uniqueness of the generated HashCodes with my algorithm. And i wrote next text class to test when the same hashCode will be generated.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var hashes = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            var vol = new Volume();
            var code = vol.GetHashCode();
            if (!hashes.Contains(code))
            {
                hashes.Add(code);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Same hash code generated on the {0} retry", hashes.Count());
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Volume
{
    public Guid DriverId = Guid.NewGuid();
    public Guid ComputerId = Guid.NewGuid();
    public int Size;
    public ulong VersionNumber;
    public int HashCode;
    public static ulong CurDriverEpochNumber;
    public static Random RandomF = new Random();

    public Volume()
    {
        Size = RandomF.Next(1000000, 1200000);
        CurDriverEpochNumber ++;
        VersionNumber = CurDriverEpochNumber;
        HashCode = GetHashCodeInternal();
    }

    public int GetHashCodeInternal()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            var one = DriverId.GetHashCode() + ComputerId.GetHashCode() * 22;
            var two = (ulong)Size + VersionNumber;
            var result = one ^ (int)two;
            return result;
        }
    } 

}
```

GUIDs fields DriverId, ComputerId and int Size are random.
I assumed that at some time we will generate the same hash-code. You know it will break work with big collections. Magic was in fact that the retry number when the duplicated
hash code is generated are the same! I run sample code for several time and got near the same result: firs run duplicate on 10170 retry, second on 7628, third 7628
and again and again on 7628. Some times i got a little bit others results. Bu in most cases it was on 7628.

It has no explanations for me. 
Is it error in . NET random generator or what?

---

Thanks all. Now it is clear the was bug in my code (Matthew Watson). I had to call GetHashCodeIntelrnal() and not GetHashCode().  The best GetHashCode unique results gave me:

```
    public int GetHashCodeInternal()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            var one = DriverId.GetHashCode() + ComputerId.GetHashCode();
            var two = ((ulong)Size) + VersionNumber;
            var result = one ^ (int)two << 32;
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Bu still on near 140 000 it give same code... i think it is not good because ve have collections near 10 000...

Comment: *You know it will break work with big collections.* - why you think that?

Comment: the random number generator is only a pseudorandom number generator (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator), which means the results are predictable in a way.

Comment: "why you think that?" - what if in the collection there is now item with the same hash code? Or what if some where there is a search by hashCode but there is hashCode for Other object? Is it normal?

Comment: You are probably using the same seed for the PRNG.

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to achieve, but your hash code algoritthms have some bad characteristics. You multiply by even composite numbers like `22` or `30`. That throws away information and gives less "dispersion" on the hashes produced. You have an `Int32` shifted by `33` to the left. That's meaningless. In C# it's interpreted as shifting by `1` intead. Again it will lose information and "dispersion" with a general `Int32` (the range being only _even_ numbers).

Comment: Hashcodes aren't supported to be unique, just nearly unique. The `Dictionary` class can handle duplicates just fine (it just gets less performant the more duplicates you have).

Comment: Jeppe Stig Nielsen... what hashCode alg i can chose for suck case?

Comment: I wanted to sift ulong to int by 33 bits at begening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change your Console.WriteLine() to also print Volume.Size like so:

```
Console.WriteLine("Same hash code generated on the {0} retry ({1})", hashes.Count, vol.Size);
```

you will see that although `hashes.Count` is always the same for the first collision, `vol.Size` is usually different.

This seems to rule out the random number generator causing this issue - it looks like some strange property of `GetHashCodeInternal()`.

Closer inspection reveals that you are calling the wrong hash code function.

This line: `var code = vol.GetHashCode();`

Should be: `var code = vol.HashCode;`

Try that instead! Because at the moment you are calling the default .Net `GetHashCode()` which is not doing what you want at all.

Comment: It's actually quite interesting, because it demonstrates just how crap the default .Net `GetHashCode()` is. I think it must be repeating when the GC decides to run, and it's kicking in at the same point each time.

Comment: What's crap about it? If the old objects have been garbage collected it is fine to reuse the same hashes.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to pass in the random number generator, having created a single one to be reused, as currently you're creating new instances of them too close together which results in the same seed being used, and hence the same sequence of numbers coming out.

Your results will  *randomly* come out seemingly random at points where the seed is generated from the next ticks/seconds of the seed date. So, just incidental, really.

Comment: Please see my code changes... (new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond)).Next(1000000, 1200000); didn't help too. What i need to do to get random?

Comment: Create the generator _outside_ of the type, and pass in the value(s) to the constructor. But remember that in a tight loop, `Next` could still be predictable - consider slot machines, where they have a random number generator running _constantly_, always generating numbers until you press a button - independent of other things -  then picks the current one. Having it run alongside, or on demand, is the wrong way to go about it.